# SQL query with ORDER before GROUP?

Tags: sql

Table "comments":

```
id    post_id  data
1     1        1
2     1        2
3     2        3
4     2        4
5     3        5
6     3        6
7     4        7
8     4        8
```

Need result table:

```
id    post_id  data
2     1        2
4     2        4
6     3        6
8     4        8
```

So as you see, I need to group by post.id, match last comment to each post and add comment data.

Comment: Ordering is not important in this case you can just use max to get the highest ID.

Comment: UPD: added data column

Comment: What's the part causing you difficutly?

Answer (score 2):

```
Select max(id) id,post_id
from table
group by post_id
```

Comment: In that way I can't match to result comment and post data

Comment: Can u pls elaborate the situation so that i can clear the issue better

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  MAX(id), post_id
FROM    mytable
GROUP BY
        post_id
```

If you need columns other than `id` (say, the whole record with the greatest `id` group-wise), use this:

```
SELECT  m.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT post_id
        FROM    mytable
        ) md
JOIN    mytable m
ON      id =
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    mytable mi
        WHERE   mi.post_id = md.post_id
        ORDER BY
                mi.post_id DESC, mi.DESC
        LIMIT 1
        )
```

Create a composite index on `mytable (post_id, id)` for this to work fast.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Comments
(
  id int,
  post_id int,
  data int
)

INSERT INTO Comments
VALUES
  (1,     1 ,       1),
  (2,     1   ,     2),
  (3,     2,        3),
  (4,     2,        4),
  (5,     3,        5),
  (6,     3,        6),
  (7,     4,        7),
  (8,     4,        8)


SELECT * INTO #Comments
FROM
(
  SELECT post_id, id, data, RANK() OVER 
      (PARTITION BY c.post_id ORDER BY c.id ASC) AS Rank
  FROM Comments c
 )a

-- SELECT * FROM #Comments

SELECT  ac.post_id, ac.id, ac.data
FROM #Comments ac
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT post_id,  Max(Rank)Rank
  FROM #Comments c
  GROUP BY post_id
)c ON c.post_id = ac.post_id AND c.Rank = ac.Rank
ORDER BY ac.post_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I found really working query:

```
SELECT * FROM posts 
LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.post_id = posts.id  
WHERE comments.id = (
    SELECT MAX(c.id) 
    FROM comments as c 
    WHERE c.post_id = posts.id
) 
OR comments.id IS NULL
```